# Showing Disk Usage Only for the Top Level Partition

Tags: disk-usage, disk

Let me begin with an example:

1. "/" or Root Filesystem is of Size 10GB and is currently 100% in Use.
2. "/usr" is a directory under "/".
3. "/usr/something" is a separate logical volume  or mount point and
   looking fine.
4. "/var" is a separate LV and looking fine too.

When we check what directory / file is consuming the disk space on the root volume, we use "du" command as shown below:

```
du -sh /*
```

However, this includes the other partitions/volumes too.

```
du -x -sh /*
```

That too, does the same thing. It does not exclude other disk volumes. However, the man page says:

> -x, --one-file-system
> skip directories on different file systems

If we see "/usr" consuming most of the disk space on the root filesystem and it is a directory under "/" then running "du -x -sh /usr/*" against it would also report on "/usr/something" which is a separate disk and is large in size causing the command to exit with much delay.

**Bottom Line:** How to show only "one filesystem" when running "du" command or any other command to identify disk usage and culprit files excluding any other disk volume under that directory / filesystem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `--exclude=[PATTERN]`?

Comment: I noticed that option, but we have multiple of such subdirectories that are logical volumes mount on. I gave a simple example in the question.

Comment: Besides, "--exclude=" is required for each pattern separately, so this thing does not work: `du -sh /* --exclude=`echo $(df -hTP -t xfs | grep -v File | awk '{print $NF}')``

Answer (score 22):

`du` is doing exactly what you told it to do.

`-x` skips directories on different file-systems, but it will do that for each and every one of the non-option arguments on the command line.

When you run `du -x -sh /*`, you are telling `du` to give you the details on **ALL** of the files and directories in `/`, **regardless of whether they are mount-points for other file-systems or not**.

`du` does not receive a single argument `/*`, it gets all the pathnames that `/*` expands to. The shell expands `/*` to **all** of the matching file/directory/sockets/fifos/etc names in `/` and passes them to `du` (actually all except those beginning with a `.` - "hidden" filenames - unless the `dotglob` shell option is set).  See `man bash` and search for `Pathname Expansion`.

What you probably want to do is use `du`'s `-d` (aka `--max-depth`) option.  e.g.

```
# du -h -x -d 1 /
512     /media
8.7M    /var
512     /srv
1.4G    /opt
10K     /tmp
512     /mnt
512     /boot
1.1M    /etc
13K     /run
512     /home
97M     /usr
1.5G    /
```

Notice how other file-systems (e.g. /proc) are excluded from the output - that's because while they match the `-d 1` maximum depth, they are also separate file-system from `/` itself, so `-x` excludes them and `du` never descends into those mount-points.

Note: `-d` is a non-standard (i.e. non-POSIX) option for `du`.  It is, however, available in both GNU and *BSD versions of `du`, and probably many others too.  i.e. this will definitely work on Linux and FreeBSD and almost certainly on other modernish unix-like systems, but may not work on ancient or proprietary unixes.

The man page extract in your question (`-x, --one-file-system skip directories on different file systems`) indicates that you are using the GNU version of `du` from GNU `coreutils`.

Comment: If i helps clarify, to a shell (such as bash, [t]csh, zsh, etc) in a un\*x environment, the parameters '/' and '/\*' are two very different things. '/' passes du only the directory name of '/', while '/\*' looks up every name _in the / directory_, and passes the whole list (_without the '/\*'_) to du. du then happily processes the whole list including the other mount points which are _part of that list_. So only use '/' and not '/\*' if you only want the filesystem mounted on '/' (i.e.: the root filesystem).

Comment: Running "du -h -x -d 1 /" also lists "/home", "/tmp", "/boot" and others which are separate filesystems / mountpoints in which I am not interested. If I get an alert stating "/ is 95% full" then I don't want to look at the contents of "/home" or "/tmp" which have no disk space issue. Also, without "-s" the size info for directories is not provided. What you get is a metadata only. On my production system it is showing "4.0K /home", for example.

Comment: It lists them because those mount points are directories in /, and directories also use some disk space (independent of the size of their contents), but it does not descend into them, because of the `-x` option, to examine the **contents** of those mount points.   4.0K is the size of the /home directory itself (probably because 4K is the minimum size of any file on your root fs), not the size of its contents.